# JQM: Pulling values from hidden fields returned by ajax call

Tags: ajax, jquery-mobile

I have a div on my jquery mobile page:

```
<div id="dynamic_div">
</div>
```

The div starts out empty. After the page is initialized, the user can add content to the div which gets added via ajax calls to the server. Note that the ajax call is made with jQuery's ajax() method.

So after an ajax call, the div will look something like this:

```
<div id="dynamic_div">
   Visible stuff
   <input hidden id="hidden_stuff" value="99">
   <a href="#" class="display_value">Display value</a>
</div>
```

Let's say I want the user to be able to click on the "Display value" link and pop open the value in the hidden field with something like this:

```
$(document).on('click', ".display_value", (function() {
  alert($('#hidden_stuff').val());
}
```

But the alert call returns "undefined," not "99." The DOM doesn't know that the `#hidden_stuff` field exists because it was loaded in via an ajax call. Is there some trick I can use to inject the hidden field into the DOM?

Comment: Turns out I was removing the HTML that contained the hidden field with javascript attached to an in onlick() event in the button. I had forgotten about this. That's why it was impossible for me to get the contents of the hidden field.

Bonehead.

Answer (score 1):

You have some typos:

The div id should have no "#": `<div id="#dynamic_div">` should be `<div id="dynamic_div">`

Your click handler:

```
$(document).on('click', ".display_value", (function() {
  alert($('#hidden_stuff').val());
}
```

should be

```
$(document).on('click', ".display_value", function() {
  alert($('#hidden_stuff').val());
});
```

> Working **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/3gnvhxth/10/)**

Comment: I was being an idiot. See my comment above. Thanks for the help.